# Accessing Static Methods on a Generic class in c#

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, static, methods

I have the following situation in code, which I suspect may be a bit dodgey:

I have a class:

```
abstract class DataAccessBase<T> : IDataAccess where T : AnotherAbstractClass
```

This class `DataAccessBase` also has a static factory method which creates instances of derived classes of itself using an enum value in a which statement to decide which derived type to create:

```
static IDataAccess CreateInstance(TypeToCreateEnum)
```

Now, the types derived from `DataAccessBase<T>` are themselves NOT generic, they specify a type for T:

```
class PoLcZoneData : DataAccessBase<PoLcZone> // PoLcZone is derived from AnotherAbstractClass
```

So far I am not sure if this is pushing the limits of good use of generics, but what I am really concerned about is how to access the static `CreateInstance()` method in the first place:

The way I am doing this at the moment is to simply pass any type T where T : `AnotherAbstractClass`.  In particular I am passing `AnotherAbstractClass` itself.  This allows compilation just fine, but it does seem to me that passing any type to a generic class just to get at the statics is a bit dodgey.

I have actually simplified the situation somewhat as `DataAccessBase<T>` is the lower level in the inheritance chain, but the static factory methods exists in a middle tier with classes such as `PoLcZoneData` being the most derived on the only level that is not generic.

What are peoples thoughts on this arrangement?

Comment: I'm sorry, its C#.  Forgot to add that to the title.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are allowed to have a non-generic class of the same name... perhaps something like:

```
abstract class DataAccessBase<T> : IDataAccess where T : AnotherAbstractClass
{
    ...
}
static class DataAccessBase
{
    public static IDataAccess CreateInstance(TypeToCreateEnum) {...}
}
```

Now you can use `DataAccessBase.CreateInstance` without any redundant `T`. Typically, you might call `internal` methods on `DataAccessBase<T>` from `DataAccessBase` - although I suspect in your scenario you might also need a little reflection / `MakeGenericType`.

Answer (score 2):

I've ran into a similar problem a while ago ("how to overload static methods") and I solved it with Reflection.

Here's my situation :

1) `public abstract class AuditObject<T> : ActiveRecordBase<T>` (yes I'm using ActiveRecord) and

2) `public class Employee : AuditObject<Employee>`

In both of them I define some static Methods, e.g.

```
public static DataTable GetLookupTable(String where, Int32 topRows)
{
    return doExtremelyCleverStuffToFetchData(where, topRows);
}
```

(in #2 you need `public **new** static` or else you get a compiler warning)

As the code is, when I call e.g.

```
DataTable myList = AuditObject<T>.GetLookupTable("inactive = 0", 100);
```

...and T is Employee, the static method is not "overriden" i.e. the one that is executed is the method in (1), not (2).

So in (1) I modified the static methods (in this example, GetLookupTable) like this :

```
public static DataTable GetLookupTable(String where, Int32 topRows)
{
    DataTable tbl = null;

    Boolean hasOverride = hasMethodOverride("GetLookupTable");

    if (hasOverride)
    {
        tbl = invokeStaticMethod<T>(
            "GetLookupTable", new Object[2] { where, topRows })
            as DataTable;
    }
    else
    {
        tbl = doExtremelyCleverStuffToFetchData(where, topRows);
    }

    return tbl;
}
```

Here's how I find out if the static method exists :

```
private static Boolean hasMethodOverride(String methodName)
{
    var methodQuery =
        from method in typeof(T).GetMethods(
            BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod)
        where method.Name == methodName
        select method;

    return methodQuery.Count() > 0;
}
```

And here's how the "override" method is called :

```
public static Object invokeStaticMethod<T>(String MethodName, Object[] Args)
{
    return typeof(T).InvokeMember(MethodName,
        BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
        null, null, Args);
}
```

Voila ! When I call `DataTable myList = AuditObject<T>.GetLookupTable("inactive = 0", 100);`
and T is Employee, I get results from the static method defined in the Employee class.

Hope this helps,

Dimitris

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything wrong with that design, specially if you are using the template parameter to specify an implementation detail. What I would suggest would be simply to have the factory function not be static, but just a stand alone. That would be the most clearcut way to go about it for me.

If you want to encapsulate it in some way I would then suggest a namespace, or a naming convention.

Yet another solution would be just hiding what you are currently doing, by defining a type of DataAccessBase maybe like so:

```
typedef DataAccessBase<AnotherAbstractClass> DataAccessBaseFactory;
```

This is my least recommended solution, but it leaves the Create function as a static if you absolutely want it to be.

Comment: Ok, in that case I guess the only option is to encapsulate the factory function in a separate class instead of a namespace